# Exception when modifying bucket writing access level with Kii Cloud SDK

Tags: android, mobile, backend, paas, kiicloud

I'm testing [Kii Cloud](http://developer.kii.com) mobile backend as a service (MBaaS) in an Android application. I'm trying to create an object in an [application level bucket](http://documentation.kii.com/en/buckets--2) *before* any user authentication takes place. For that I want to modify the app bucket to allow anonymous users to write to it:

```
        Kii.initialize("my_app_id", "my_app_key", Kii.Site.US);

        KiiBucket bucket = Kii.bucket("app_status");

        KiiACL ubACL = bucket.acl();
        ubACL.putACLEntry(new KiiACLEntry(KiiAnonymousUser.create(), KiiACL.BucketAction.CREATE_OBJECTS_IN_BUCKET, true));
        ubACL.save(new KiiACLCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSaveCompleted(int token, KiiACL acl, Exception exception) {
                if (exception != null)
                    Toast.makeText(getInstance().getApplicationContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
```

But I always get an exception when trying to save the ACL (onSaveCompleted() returns with an exception):

```
com.kii.cloud.storage.exception.ACLOperationException: Error: null
HTTP Response Status: 403
HTTP Response Body: {
  "errorCode" : "WRONG_TOKEN",
  "message" : "The provided token is not valid",
  "appID" : "bc4100c0",
  "accessToken" : "null",
  "suppressed" : [ ]
}
```

I'm passing my app_id and app_key correctly in the beginning (first line of sample code). Any ideas what could be causing this error? Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
KiiAnonymousUser.create()
```

with

```
new KiiAnonymousUser()
```

It seems the static create() method has been removed.

Best

Comment: Thanks, now I get another error "bucket not found", but this solved the previous error message :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. My code snippet for sure will cause exceptions because custom access control via ACL can only be applied to group and user level buckets (not app level buckets)